# mysql - updating based on 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I try to update 3 tables at same time. clients.id > cars.client_id > works.car_id is indefication

```
UPDATE clients, cars, works 
JOIN cars on cars.client_id = clients.id 
JOIN works on works.car_id = cars.id 
SET clients.name = '15-adsadadadsa' , 
clients.email = '15-aaa@aa.com' , 
clients.phone = '15-3232131', 
clients.email = '15-aaa@aa.com' , 
cars.reg = 'aaa-aaa' , 
cars.model = 'aaa-aaa' , 
cars.year = '111111' , works.work = 'aaaa' WHERE works.id = '15';
```

But get error

Not unique table/alias: 'cars'

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

That's because `cars` table is mentioned twice (in `UPDATE` as well as `JOIN`), you don't need to mention the table names in `UPDATE` if they are in `JOIN`, try this:

```
UPDATE clients
JOIN cars on cars.client_id = clients.id 
JOIN works on works.car_id = cars.id 
SET clients.name = '15-adsadadadsa' , 
clients.email = '15-aaa@aa.com' , 
clients.phone = '15-3232131', 
clients.email = '15-aaa@aa.com' , 
cars.reg = 'aaa-aaa' , 
cars.model = 'aaa-aaa' , 
cars.year = '111111' , works.work = 'aaaa' WHERE works.id = '15';
```